# How do I make a unit test work as shown on my book?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning Rails, and studying Unit testing. One of the books I'm using gives a example that, apparently, was written wrong.

This is the validation:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :image_url, :price, :title

  #VALIDATION PROCESS

  validates :title, :description, :image_url, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 10}
  validates :price, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01}
  validates :title, :uniqueness => true
  validates  :image_url, :format => {
    :with => %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$}i,
    :message => 'Must be a URL for GIF,PNG or JPG image!'
  }
end
```

And this is the test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "product price must be positive" do

  product = Product.new(:title => "My Book Title" ,
  :description => "yyy" ,
  :image_url => "zzz.jpg" )

  product.price= -1
  assert product.invalid?
  assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01" ,
  product.errors[:price].join('; ' )

  product.price = 0
  assert product.invalid?
  assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01" ,
  product.errors[:price].join('; ' )

  product.price = 1
  assert product.valid?

  end

end
```

When I run the test on the command line using `rake test:units`, I get a failure in the the last assertion:

```
product.price = 1
assert product.valid?
```

It says `Failured assertion, no message given`.

The strange thing is that the book itself says that this particular assertion is true, so nothing should be happening during the test.

So, what's up with that? Is the code wrong, or am I doing something wrong, or is it right and I'm just confused?

Answer (score 0):

You have add a validator

```rb
validates :title, :description, :image_url, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 10}
```

Which requires the `:title`, `:description`, and `:image_url` field to have at least 10 characters. However, you created a product with `:description => 'yyy'`, `:image_url => "zzz.jpg"`, which should be the cause of the validation failure.

And, you can always check program status with `Kernel#p`, `Kernel#puts` or some other output technique. Dump the variable status where you are confused, check the program output and see if you can find out the cause of failure. That's useful when writing programs and worth trying.

Here, you can always check `errors` field of `product` after calling `product.valid?`.

```rb
# change
product.price = 1
assert product.valid?

# to 
product.price = 1
puts ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>DUMP"
puts product.valid?
p product.errors
```

Comment: I just added another 10 characters on the description attr, making it 14 characters in total... and i still get the failure. So the issue is not on the description.

And sorry, i dont know how to do this Kernel#p technique, i'm a complete beginner in software development.

Comment: @Gracko As what I have said, just replace the two lines with the the code using `Kernel#p`, run the test case and check the output. Find out which part is printed by `p` and check if you can find something useful.

Comment: @Gracko All of your `:title`, `:description` and `:image_url` are restricted by the `:length` validator, you should update your `:image_url` field also.

Comment: @Gracko If you have problem with `Kernel#p`, go read the Ruby documentation or find some Ruby books. You should be prepared in Ruby before actually coding in Ruby on Rails.